# $http.get() returns html and not json

Tags: angularjs

Using $http.get() on a json file, but the response is the HTML code to the page I am using.  That is, console.log(response) prints the entire test.html file.

main.js is ran on nodejs, which loads test.html.  test.html then should load test.json.  The console.log('here') prints and $scope.hello is set and displays correctly.

main.js

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    var data = fs.readFile('test.html', function(err,data) {
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        response.write(data);
        response.end();
    });
}).listen(8081);
```

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js">
    </script>

    <script>
    angular.module('App', []).controller('Ctrl', 
        function($scope, $http) {
            console.log('here');
            $http.get('test.json').success(function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                $scope.hello = "hi guys";
            });
        }
    );
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <p>{{hello}}</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

test.json

```
  { "papers" :[
     {
       "authors":"Zubrin, Robert M.; Baker, David A.; Gwynne, Owen",
       "title":"Mars Direct: A Simple, Robust, And Cost Effective Architecture For The Space Exploration Initiative",
       "titleLink":"http://www.marspapers.org/papers/Zubrin_1991.pdf",
       "abstractName":"Abstract",
       "abstractLink":"http://www.marspapers.org/abstr/Zubrin_1991abstr.htm",     
       "year":"1991",
       "category":"MissionEngring",
       "publcation":""
     }
 ]}
```

Comment: What html it is posting .. that may be some error coded it think Update your Post with that for some quick help..

Comment: One More thing in your server Side coding you need to send response in  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'application/json'}); not text/html

Comment: instead of sending test.html you need to query your db and then return the response in json then it works !!

Comment: The HTML is literally what I posted for test.html.  Changing the content type does not work.  My original problem was when I was using just test.html and test.json.  I got an error trying to load test.json because it was cross origin.  So I decided to host everything on nodejs.

Comment: That's not at all how you "host everything on node.js". You've written a web server that only knows how to respond with one specific piece of content, regardless of what is requested of it. `test.json` is not used here. You could delete it from disk. Node doesn't know about it because you have no path through your code that can ever possibly open and serve the contents of `test.json`. Your node server **only** knows how to spit out `test.html` not matter what URL is requested.

Answer (score 0):

Your server is specifically programmed to return the contents of `test.html` regardless of what is requested. You need to actually inspect `request` and serve the appropriate file.

Comment: I do not follow.  Yes, node will return the contents of test.html, but I would think when I load the page the angular part will run and load the json file.

Comment: @joshbaldwin42 Angular can only load the data you serve it, and no matter what you request from node, you have specifically programmed node to return the contents of `test.html`. You could go to `http://localhost:8081/iiwugeiugifugiugwygfiugriqgriuqgr` and you'll get `test.html`'s content. You could go to `http://localhost:8081/test.json` and you'll get `test.html`'s content.  No matter what URL you ask for, you have specifically programmed node to **ignore the request** and serve up the contents of `test.html`.

Comment: I think I understand.  I was assuming $http.get() was being done on the angular side, but I need to add this functionality within the $http.createServer() function to handle this request.  Sounds like I need to look into node more.  Thanks!

Comment: You need to refer some Sample Node js apps or MEANJS startup template which gives you Good idea about Node and angular http://meanjs.org/